# Setting WPLANG from a plugin

Tags: multi-language, translation

For a single site wordpress, the language must be set from `wp-config.php`'s `WPLANG`, but is it possible to set from my plugin which override the default value?

Comment: The link also appears at the right column of this page, but I think it's worth noting in the comments another approach for a similar situation: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/53678/12615

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In `wp-includes/l10n.php` you will find the function `get_locale()`. It offers a filter;  you can set the language and ignore the constant:

```
function get_locale() {
    global $locale;

    if ( isset( $locale ) )
        return apply_filters( 'locale', $locale );

    // WPLANG is defined in wp-config.
    if ( defined( 'WPLANG' ) )
        $locale = WPLANG;

    // If multisite, check options.
    if ( is_multisite() ) {
        // Don't check blog option when installing.
        if ( defined( 'WP_INSTALLING' ) || ( false === $ms_locale = get_option( 'WPLANG' ) ) )
            $ms_locale = get_site_option('WPLANG');

        if ( $ms_locale !== false )
            $locale = $ms_locale;
    }

    if ( empty( $locale ) )
        $locale = 'en_US';

    return apply_filters( 'locale', $locale );
}
```

To change it per plugin use the filter `'locale'`. Example:

```
add_filter( 'locale', 'wpse_52419_change_language' );
function wpse_52419_change_language( $locale )
{
    return 'de_DE';
}
```

Comment: Works like a magic. But in my case, it's returning an error: `Fatal error: Cannot redeclare get_locale()`. So I simply changed the function name from `get_locale()` to `nano_get_locale()`, and it's working wonderfully.

Comment: @MayeenulIslam You should **not** copy the `get_locale()` function, that’s a quote from the core. All you need is the last code block.

Comment: great @toscho, many thanks. However, this does not work if I switch OPCache on on my local MAMPpro... is that like it is or is there a solution?

Comment: @RaphaelJeger This cannot be affected by OPCache, only an output chache can do that. If you still have this problem, ask a new question.