# How to dynamically change the locale?

Tags: localization, language, session

Sorry about making this so lengthy. I just want to explain everything clearly and walk you through what I have tried so far to solve this problem.

There is an English and a Spanish version of the website, which hopefully can be toggled between. I have a session variable $_SESSION['language_code'] that I am trying to use to dynamically set the locale and use a different language file.

I should note first off that the session is working properly. I have $_SESSION['language_code']='es_US' hard set for testing, which is echoed at the top of the < body > just so I can see that it is working. I also know that the language files are working, because I can set the defined variable in wp-config define('WPLANG', 'es_US'); and I can see that translations work from my .po/.mo files.

Instead of changing WPLANG, I can also use a filter to get this to work, like so:

```
function spark_change_language( $locale ){
    return 'es_US';
}
add_filter( 'locale', 'spark_change_language' );
```

or:

```
function spark_change_language( $locale ){
    $locale = 'es_US';
    return $locale;
}
add_filter( 'locale', 'spark_change_language' );
```

I can do all this and see the translations work properly on the website. The problems arise when I try to change the locale dynamically. I can set the $_SESSION variable to a different language code and try to change the locale using that, but for whatever reason the filter function gives some very odd behavior. I'm trying to do this like [Setting WPLANG from a plugin](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/52419/setting-wplang-from-a-plugin) or [Change locale at runtime?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/49451/change-locale-at-runtime)

Here is what I tried first:

```
function spark_change_language( $locale ){
return $_SESSION['language_code'];
}
add_filter( 'locale', 'spark_change_language' );
```

That should do it right? Especially if $_SESSION['language_code']='es_US'. Well, in this example it just generates an error: **Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION** ...

Alright, so $_SESSION clearly isn't created by the time the filter runs for 'locale'. *OR IS IT?*

If I add some conditionals, it seems to act like $_SESSION is totally available:

```
function spark_change_language( $locale ){
    if( isset($_SESSION['language_code']) ){

        if( $_SESSION['language_code']=='es_US' ){
            $locale = 'es_US';
        }
    }

    return $locale;
}
add_filter( 'locale', 'spark_change_language' );
```

No errors here, but 'es_US' is still not being returned as the language code, or at least the website is not being translated. Now I can already hear you, it's because isset() is returning false since I got that "Undefined variable" notice, so it just skips that part and goes straight to `return $locale;`, right? *RIGHT?*

Well, I added a way to test how far it gets into the conditionals, and the conditionals are returning TRUE. In my header.php, right after the opening < body> tag I have `<?php do_action('spark_body_start'); ?>` and I created a function like so:

```
function test_alert(){ ?>
    <script>alert('ohai');</script>
<?php   
}
```

... and I used add_action() in the locale function, like so:

```
function spark_change_language( $locale ){
    if( isset($_SESSION['language_code']) ){

        if( $_SESSION['language_code']=='es_US' ){
            $locale = 'es_US';
            add_action('spark_body_start','test_alert');
        }
    }

    return $locale;
}
add_filter( 'locale', 'spark_change_language' );
```

Now upon refreshing the page, I get a javascript alert that says "ohai". But wait, that's within the conditionals that check if $_SESSION['language_code'] exists and if it's set to 'es_US'. So since the javascript alert appeared, I know that the add_action() ran, which means `$locale = 'es_US';`, which means both of the conditionals were TRUE. So $_SESSION *does exist* by the time this function runs, even though the previous example gave an undefined variable notice? And the page still doesn't get translated into Spanish.

Alright, well maybe I just can't return a variable, maybe it has to be a string. That's fine, I can write the function like this:

```
function spark_change_language( $locale ){
    if( isset($_SESSION['language_code']) ){

        if( $_SESSION['language_code']=='es_US' ){
            add_action('spark_body_start','test_alert');
            return 'es_US';
        }
    }

    return $locale;
}
add_filter( 'locale', 'spark_change_language' );
```

Now I refresh the page and the 'ohai' alert appears, so it must get to the `return 'es_US';` line. However, the page still isn't translated.

What, then, is actually getting returned by this filter?! Why is $_SESSION defined in conditionals, but not outside of them? Why does the filter work when I set a return value outside of conditionals, but it doesn't work if the return value is set within conditionals?

And for my main problem, is there actually a way to get the language to change dynamically, using the .po/.mo files? We don't want to use Google Translate due to accuracy concerns. A dynamic solution is also preferable since we will end up having over 200 languages.

---

**UPDATE**

---

Alright, I think I figured this out.

I think my problem was that I was using the “standard” way of starting a session in my functions.php:

`function myStartSession() {
    if(!session_id()) {
        session_start();
    }
}
add_action('init', 'myStartSession', 1);`

I don’t think it made session available “soon enough”.

I followed another example (http://codeblow.com/questions/how-you-can-alter-the-value-wplang-in-wordpress-by-visiting-a/) and reworked it into my wp-config.php file:

```
if(!session_id()) {
    session_start();
}

//First check if the $_GET value is there. This occurs when someone clicks the link to change the language...
if ( isset($_GET['lang']) ){

    // Check that it's either 'es_US' (USA Spanish/Espanol) or 'en_US' (USA English), and set the $_SESSION['WPLANG'] accordingly.
    if( $_GET['lang']=='es_US' ){
        $_SESSION['WPLANG'] = 'es_US';

    } elseif( $_GET['lang']=='en_US' ){
        $_SESSION['WPLANG'] = 'en_US';

    } else {
        //Fall back to the default if it's not es_US or en_US.
        $_SESSION['WPLANG'] = '';
    }
    // Once the $_SESSION['WPLANG'] is set, define it's value to WPLANG.
    define ('WPLANG', $_SESSION['WPLANG']);

//... otherwise if $_GET wasn't set, check if $_SESSION['WPLANG'] was already set previously...
} elseif( isset($_SESSION['WPLANG']) ){

    // If it's es_US or en_US, define WPLANG as such.
    if( $_SESSION['WPLANG']=='es_US' || $_SESSION['WPLANG']=='en_US' ){
        define ('WPLANG', $_SESSION['WPLANG']);

    } else {
        //Fall back to the default if it's not es_US or en_US.
        define ('WPLANG', '');
    }

//... and finally just set WPLANG to a blank string (default value).
} else {
    define ('WPLANG', '');
}
```

So it’s not as nice as using the filters/actions, but it works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change locale manually at runtime?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/49451/change-locale-manually-at-runtime)