# Translation of theme using PO files

Tags: translation

We are currently building a site that needs to handle multiple languages. We are doing this using PO files. My question is, for the front-end user we will provide a language change facility. How do I make WordPress read from these different WordPress files depending on what language the user has chosen?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use a filter "In wp-includes/l10n.php you will find the function get_locale(). It offers a filter; you can set the language and ignore the constant:" `add_filter( 'locale', 'wpse_52419_change_language' );
function wpse_52419_change_language( $locale )
{
    return 'de_DE';
}`- http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/52419/setting-wplang-from-a-plugin/52436#52436

Comment: @stemie Great, that does the trick thanks very much!